# How to set a variable on modal with bootstrap3-dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
error = false;  

if( error == false){             
  BootstrapDialog.show({                 
    title: 'Atention',                 
    message:`There was an error`,                 
    data: {'error': error,},                 
    buttons: [
      {label: 'Close', action: function (dialogItself) { error=true; dialogItself.close(); }},
      {label: 'Keep going', cssClass: 'btn-success', action: function (dialogItself) { error=false; dialogItself.close(); }}
    ]             
  });
} 

console.log(error);
```

And the problem is that this always return error = false. How could I set the variable with the modal buttons?

I expect to be able to set the variable inside de modal

Comment: Define error as a let ->   let error = false;    See if that fixes it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment because my reputation is > 50, so I'll try to answer. Your code is actually working as far as I can tell, but I'm not sure that I understand your question.

Try logging the `error` variable when the modal closes using the `onhidden` event function. Here's an example and a jsfiddle link:

```
error = false;
if (error == false) {
   BootstrapDialog.show({
      title: 'Atention',
      message: `There was an error`,
      data: { 'error': error, },
      onhidden: function(dialogItself) {
        console.log("onhidden: error = " + error);
      },
      buttons: [
        { label: 'Close', action: function(dialogItself) { error = true; dialogItself.close(); } },
        { label: 'Keep going', cssClass: 'btn-success', action: function(dialogItself) { error = false; dialogItself.close(); } }
      ]
   });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6s3rhdmk/4/